# MongoError: multi update only works with $ operators while using bulk find and update in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, bulkupdate

Why getting error

> MongoError: multi update only works with $ operators

while using `bulk find and update` to update multiple document.

Tried :

```
var bulk = db.collection('users').initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

var emails = ['a@gmail.com', 'b@gmail.com', 'c@gmail.com','d@gmail.com'];
var allStatus = ['s1', 's2', 's3', ''];

for (var i =0; i< allStatus.length; i++) {
  var query = { email: emails[i], status: { '$ne': allStatus[i] } };
  var updateField = {};
  if(allStatus[i]) {
      updateField = {
        $set: {status: allStatus[i], date: new Date()},
        $push: {
          notes: {note: 'jdf'+i, date: new Date()},
          history: {status: allStatus[i], date: new Date()}
        }
      };
  }
  bulk.find(query).update(updateField);
}

bulk.execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got what was the problem and solved that problem

The error

> MongoError: multi update only works with $ operators

occurred when `updateField` is empty object like `updateField = {}`. When I was trying to update a record with **empty object** then was getting this error for `bulk` update.

so before pun into the bulk checked that the `updateField` is **empty** or not. put into the `bulk` operation if not **empty** object

like:

```
if(Object.keys(updateField).length) {
   bulk.find(query).update(updateField);
}
```

By this way I solved my problem